# EvanBetterAuthorizationSample Integration Issue

Tags: macos, applescript, root, vpn, keychain

I am trying to store PASSWORD AND SHAREDSECRETKEY in SYSTEM keychain and for that i am using Apple's`EvanBetterAuthorizationSample` code.

I tried to use `SMJobBlessUtil.py` tool.

I tried the 1st function to `“setreq”` which is giving me error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SMJobBlessUtil.py", line 424, in <module>
    main()
  File "./SMJobBlessUtil.py", line 418, in main
    setreq(appArgs[1], appArgs[2], appArgs[3:])
  File "./SMJobBlessUtil.py", line 360, in setreq
    appToolDict[bundleID] = toolNameToReqMap[bundleID]
KeyError: ‘myappbundleid'
```

and then I try `check` command which is saying me that app code signature invalid.

```
./SMJobBlessUtil.py check build/Debug/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample.app : app code signature invalid
```

It looks like there is some thing wrong with my certificates.
I just replace `com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS` to my application bundle id everywhere and selected my application’s provisioning profile.

I follow steps from readme file's **Adopting this technology** Section  from EvenBetterAuthorizationSample code as Apple says they are the integration steps but it doesn't looks like steps as i didn't find any proper implementation step.

Can any one guide me in this where else i still need to make changes.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean this <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html>?

Comment: yes... i am just trying to modify the apple's EvenBetterAuthorizationExample code by changing my identifier and certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake that my Bundle ID and Helper Tool id Does not match and that cause me errors.

Comment: @Malvi Soni. I am facing same problem. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 3):

Under HelperTool target > Build Settings: Make sure that "Product Name and "Product Module Name" are the same as the Helper Tool identifier.

[image]

Comment: @Mani Khalil : I add the image. Did I help you?